# Switching the values Year and Day fields in a list of type DateTime

Tags: c#, list, date, datetime

I have a `C# list` which has Dates in it in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. Now, I want to process the list such that the value in Day field is considered as `Year` and `Day` can be any number should be equal throughout the list and store the processed data in another `list`

For example, I have following rows in the list

```
SourceList

01/15/2014   
12/14/2014
02/16/2014
```

I want a method which processes the list and gives the following data

```
ResultList

01/10/2015   
12/10/2014
02/10/2016
```

As you can see from the above data we can see that from above `ResultList`, the `Day` field in `SourceList` for the first element `15` is the `Year` field `2015` in the `ResultList` and similarly for the second element `Day 14` is transformed to `Year 2014` and for third `Day 16` is transformed to `Year 2016` in `ResultList`. day can be any number

I used the following code to import data from excel sheet

```
var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\Parser.xlsx", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

            var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", fileName);

            var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] ", connectionString);
            var ds = new DataSet();

            adapter.Fill(ds, "axiomData");

            DataTable data = ds.Tables["axiomData"];

            List<DataRow> listAxiomData = data.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

Comment: wait. how you process the list. can you show the code?

Comment: you need to show all relevant code.. it's hard to tell what you're expecting based on what you have shown and you also said the number in the middle can be any number so I wonder, why it's returning `x`

Comment: I am just getting it from an excel sheet.I just wanted to show you any number as 'x' Please look at the edited question

Comment: Are you asking why your code is changing the years or asking for code to do it?  Either way you need to add what you've already tried

Comment: @Saggio. Well, my code is not changing anything. I just want a way to switch day and year. I have no idea of approach to it

Comment: you can just use `ToString()` method to change the format e.g. `Datetime.ToString("MM/yyyy/dd")`

Comment: @Saggio Well, that would just change the format and still have year value as same in the source list. Please compare my SourceList and ResultList, you will find the difference

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what you're expecting as in your question you say `day can be any number`

Comment: @Saggio I tried to be very clear but what exactly I want is if Day field in Date is 15 then I want the Year to be 2015(regardless of what year it has before) and after changing all the years now, process the day fields and make them equal to other Day fields of other elements. Please make sure that when I mentioned Day field then it is just the Day not the entire Date. If it is still unclear, I would be happy to close the question

Comment: @Saggio In this, I just want you to deal with Day fields and year field depends on the Day field. Please take a close look at both my source and result list with regarding to Day and Year fields and see how they differ from each other. Is is the best way I could explain

Comment: @Dev I am a little confused on where you got the 10 for the day in your example. I made an answer, but still need some clarification for the day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(var item in SourceList)
{
    int newYear = Convert.ToInt32(item.Year.ToString().Substring(0,2) + item.Day.ToString());
    DateTime result = new DateTime(newYear, item.Month, 10);
    ResultList.Add(result);
}
```

Should work.

Comment: Perfectly Worked! Thanks and you got it

Comment: @Dev Glad to hear it :)